# IColumn in DetailsList: how to set column width at mount

Tags: office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

How can you set the columns of a DetailsList to a specific width at mount?k

I wanted to save the column widths every time they are saved and restore them when the component remounts, i.e., revisits the view where the list is.

Answer (score 3):

```
return [...staticColumns, ...visibleColumns.map(c => {
    return  {
        key: c.Name,
        name: c.Title,
        fieldName: c.Name, 
        minWidth: 100,
        isResizable: true,
        isCollapsible: true,
        onRender: (item: any, index: number, column: IColumn) => {
          column.minWidth = 20;
          return <span>{item[c.Name]}</span>;
        },
    } as IColumn;
})];
```

First set initial `minWidth: 100`, then change to 20 in the `onRender` callback. It's work for me

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! But there's even a better one if you use `onRenderHeader` callback which is only invoked once per column and not per each table cell as `onRender`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this. Guess you can't easily.

https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/9287